# same row content repeat in the whole page grid while navigate pagination

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, uicomponent

[image]The problem :

When you apply filter or pagination, then removing filter, same row content being repeat in the whole page grid.
Here is the file where I am making mistakes?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../Magento/Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">    

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing_columns</item>
    </argument>    
    <dataSource name="replacement_member_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Aayanshtech\Replacement\Ui\DataProvider\MemberDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">w_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render" />
                 </item>
               <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">w_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>        
    </dataSource>    
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridAcions</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/save"/>
                        <item name="deleteUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/delete"/>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>       
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridFilters</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filters</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterInput name="order_number">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">order_number</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Number</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterInput>
             <filterInput name="first_name">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">first_name</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">First Name</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterInput>
              <filterInput name="email">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">email</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterInput>
        </filters>
           <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                      <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">w_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <!-- Mass actions which you want to add in your grid-->
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="replacement/grid/massdelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="massemail">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">massemail</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Send E-Mails</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="replacement/grid/massemail"/>                       
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
         <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing.replacement_records_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>    
    <columns name="replacement_member_listing_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                  <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">w_id</item>
                    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="replacement/index/InlineEdit"/>
                        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                 <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing.replacement_member_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">w_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
          <column name="w_id">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">number</item>
           <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Id</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column> 
       <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
    <column name="order_number">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order number</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>   
        <column name="first_name">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">First Name</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>   
       <column name="email">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>   
         <column name="track_code">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                  </item>                
                  <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                  <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Track Code</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column> 
       <column name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Aayanshtech\Replacement\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Status</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
       <!-- Add Action with each row of grid and for this we will create a class Action -->
       <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Aayanshtech\Replacement\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Action">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                   <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </actionsColumn>      
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I updated this

```
    <dataSource component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider" name="xigen_testimonial_testimonial_listing_data_source">
        <settings>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
    <aclResource>Xigen_Testimonial::Testimonial</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" name="xigen_testimonial_testimonial_listing_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>testimonial_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
```

To this

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Testimonial/blob/master/view/adminhtml/ui_component/xigen_testimonial_testimonial_listing.xml#L21-L38

```
<dataSource name="xigen_testimonial_testimonial_listing_data_source">
        <aclResource>Xigen_Testimonial::Testimonial</aclResource>
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">xigen_testimonial_testimonial_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">testimonial_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" path="mui/index/render" xsi:type="url"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">testimonial_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
```

Answer (score 12):

Just add storageConfig under the settings tag. It will fix the duplicate rows problem when sorting UI grid columns multiple times.

```
<dataSource name="xigen_testimonial_testimonial_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
    <settings>
        <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        <storageConfig>
            <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">testimonial_id</param>
        </storageConfig>
    </settings>
    <aclResource>Magento_Sales::sales_order</aclResource>
    <dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" name="xigen_testimonial_testimonial_listing_data_source">
        <settings>
            <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
            <primaryFieldName>testimonial_id</primaryFieldName>
        </settings>
    </dataProvider>
</dataSource>
```

Hope it helps others too.